# T-SQL stored procedure executes select twice?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

```
DROP PROCEDURE showMatchOnDate
go

CREATE PROCEDURE showMatchOnDate 
     @MatchDate DATE
AS
    DECLARE @tempTeams TABLE
                       (
                           Id CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
                           name VARCHAR(40),
                           nomatches INT,
                           owngoals INT,
                           othergoals INT,
                           points INT
                       )

    INSERT INTO @tempTeams(Id, name, nomatches, owngoals, othergoals, points)
        SELECT * FROM teams

    DECLARE @homeGoals INT
    DECLARE @outGoals INT
    DECLARE @homeID CHAR(3)
    DECLARE @outID CHAR(3)

    DECLARE @count INT
    DECLARE @totalAmount INT

    SET @totalAmount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matches WHERE matchdate <= @MatchDate)
    SET @count = 1

    SELECT @totalAmount

    WHILE (@count <= @totalAmount)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @homeGoals = (SELECT homegoal FROM matches WHERE Id = @count)
        SELECT @outGoals = (SELECT outgoal FROM matches WHERE Id = @count)
        SELECT @homeID = (SELECT homeid FROM matches WHERE Id = @count)
        SELECT @outID = (SELECT outid FROM matches WHERE Id = @count)

        UPDATE @tempTeams
        SET nomatches = nomatches + 1
        WHERE Id = @homeID OR Id = @outID

        UPDATE @tempTeams
        SET owngoals = owngoals + @homeGoals
        WHERE Id = @homeID

        UPDATE @tempTeams
        SET owngoals = owngoals + @outGoals
        WHERE Id = @outID

        UPDATE @tempTeams
        SET othergoals = othergoals + @outGoals
        WHERE Id = @homeID

        UPDATE @tempTeams
        SET othergoals = othergoals + @homeGoals
        WHERE Id = @outID

        UPDATE @tempTeams
        SET points = points + 3
        WHERE Id = @homeID AND @homeGoals > @outGoals

        UPDATE @tempTeams
        SET points = points + 3
        WHERE Id = @outID AND @outGoals > @homeGoals

        IF @outGoals = @homeGoals
            UPDATE @tempTeams
            SET points = points + 1
            WHERE Id = @homeID OR (Id = @outID)

        SET @count = @count + 1
    END

    SELECT * FROM @tempTeams
go
```

For some reason when I run this, I get a duplicate of every single item. which I don't want. Obviously I want the correct value which should be 154 different items. But instead I get 308, and every item is duplicated. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I only see one insert from the @TempTeams, so you should get whatever count returned for that insert.    Did you run this select from SQL directly to confirm count there?  select * from teams  (and should not use select *, should select the fields only that you need (even if it is all of them) because if you update table structure later it will break this SP

Comment: Also what SQL technology?

Comment: What makes you think 154 is the correct value?

Comment: Its Tsql in Microsoft SQL server Management and i know it has to be 154 cause thats hoe many inserts exist in the original table

Answer (score 0):

Check first your "teams" table, you could have an extra data here, If so, dele the duplicate ones.

Also best practices requires to write the explicit fields to avoid errors in the future, something like this:

```
insert into @tempTeams(Id,name,nomatches,owngoals,othergoals,points)
   select Id,name,nomatches,owngoals,othergoals,points
   from teams
```